# How to detect a Windows network path?

Tags: python, windows, path

I am writing a script which runs a Windows executable file in a directory supplied by a user. If this script is a network path, making it the current directory will look like it worked, but running any commands in this directory will fail:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir(r'\\server\share\folder') # my actual name is different but similar
>>> os.getcwd()
'\\\\server\\share\\folder'
>>> os.system('echo %CD%')
'\\server\share\folder'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
C:\Windows
0
```

I want to predict this situation in my script — if the user supplies a network path instead of a local path like `c:\work\project42`, give a meaningful error immediately instead of letting it fail later.

How can I determine if a path is a Windows network path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the simplest check is `yourpathstring.startswith(r'\\')`.

However, this will be a false-positive for any linux path which starts with `\\` (unlikely but possible) and a false-negative when people use forward slashes: `//server\share\folder`.

It appears that the library function `splitdrive` was designed with network path support in mind. The network part is considered "drive", so just have to check if it's a non-DOS drive:

```
def is_network_path(path):
    drive = os.path.splitdrive(path)[0]
    if drive:
        return not drive.endswith(':')
    else:
        return False
```

Probably not worth the effort, but it "feels" more correct.

Answer (score 2):

I mean, in your example, a simple `yourpathstring.startswith(r('\\'))` would seem appropriate, but:

The Windows path system is quite mighty, and you cannot tell whether something is a classical DOS/Win9x era local path that's actually a network mount ("network drive" style), or whether something is a local path started from the alternative ways of traversing the path hierarchy. Compare the complexity of the [`getFullPathname`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfullpathnamea) function.

In other words, from the path alone, not even Windows can directly tell you whether something is local or remote.

So, the solution is simply not using `CMD` of all things to do your job on paths that might be UNC paths (the problem is the path, not the networky-ness of it). Fast forward 3 decades and use a different shell/script interpreter (powershell, VB.NET,…)

Answer (score 1):

You want to detect a UNC path.

You can simply do:

```
r'\\server\share\folder'.startswith(os.sep*2)
```

To workaround this issue, it's better to avoid to change directory altogether and adapt the called program arguments if possible so the command runs in the current (valid) directory.

Another workaround would be to mount a drive with the `net use` command (basically what `pushd` and `popd` commands do, see [Browse an UNC path using Windows CMD without mapping it to a network drive](https://superuser.com/questions/282963/browse-an-unc-path-using-windows-cmd-without-mapping-it-to-a-network-drive)).

Then Windows accepts to start processes in that directory.

If you are a sysadmin you can also just disable that unc check by setting this registry key: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor\DisableUNCCheck` but then the code will depend on that key which is rarely by default on machines.